Path value cannot be null error in nextflow
I am trying to learn nextflow and use the process and workflow below to align some Chip seq reads.
For the command below, I am getting the error: Path value cannot be null
My genome index files are named human_hg38_index.*.bt2 within the folder that I have specified within params.genome.
I was wondering how do I fix this error?
Thanks!
#!/usr/bin/env nextflow

params.reads = '/Volumes/matthews/AHR_ER_project_files/FASTQ/TCDD_AHR_Rep_ChIPSeq_1.fastq.gz'
params.genome = '/Users/siddhaduio.no/Desktop/All_omics_tools/bowtie2-2.4.4-macos-x86_64/hg38_index/'
params.outdir = '/Volumes/matthews/AHR_ER_project_files/FASTQ/results'

workflow {
  fastq_reads = channel.fromPath(params.reads)
  index_file= channel.fromPath(params.genome)

  ALIGNMENT(index_file,fastq_reads)
}

process ALIGNMENT {
  tag {"ALIGNMENT {sample_id}"} 
  label 'bowtie2'
    publishDir "${params.outdir}/bowtie2_align", mode:'copy', pattern: "*.bam"

  input:

    path genome
    tuple val( sample_id ), path( reads )

  output:

    path( "{sample_id}.aligned.bam" ), emit: aligned_bam

  script:
    """
    /Users/siddhaduio.no/Desktop/All_omics_tools/bowtie2-2.4.4-macos-x86_64/bowtie2 -p 64 -q -x {genome} -U {sample_id}.fastq.gz -S {sample_id}.aligned.bam
    """
} 


If you are certain your input files exist, I think the issue might be that the fromPath factory method emits file paths, but your ALIGNMENT process is expecting a tuple. One solution is to use the map operator to transform the input channel into a tuple, for example (untested and ignoring the publishDir directive):
params.reads = '/Volumes/matthews/AHR_ER_project_files/FASTQ/TCDD_AHR_Rep_ChIPSeq_1.fastq.gz'
params.genome = '/Users/siddhaduio.no/Desktop/All_omics_tools/bowtie2-2.4.4-macos-x86_64/hg38_index/human_hg38_index.*.bt2'

process ALIGNMENT {

    tag "ALIGNMENT ${sample_id}"

    conda 'bowtie2'

    input:
    tuple val(sample_id), path(reads)
    path bowtie_index

    output:
    tuple val(sample_id), path("{sample_id}.aligned.bam"), emit: aligned_bam

    script:
    def bt2_idx = bowtie_index[0].simpleName

    """
    bowtie2 \\
        -p 64 \\
        -q \\
        -x "${bt2_idx}" \\
        -U "${reads.join(',')}" \\
        -S "${sample_id}.aligned.bam"
    """
}

workflow {

    fastq_reads = channel.fromPath( params.reads ).map { fastq ->
        tuple( fastq.simpleName, fastq )
    }

    bowtie_index_files = files( params.genome )


    ALIGNMENT( fastq_reads, bowtie_index_files )
}

Run using:
nextflow run main.nf -with-conda

